# dynamically populate select dropdown depending from previous select dropdown choice and validate

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have been trying to get a function; switchState()" to function to validate the inputs.

My expertise in in the creative area and so am being driven bonkers trying to get this to function correctly.

How it should run;
A choice is made from the dropdown, "state", The user then has to enter a postcode. Validation is made depending on state chosen, displaying a green background if correct or red if not.

I trust someone can help me.

Many thanks in advance...a.matt.

The html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Country:
    <select class="uk-form-select" name="country" id="country" type="text" placeholder="select country first">
      <option value="0">select country</option>
      <option value="AU">Australia</option>
      <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>State:
    <select type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="select state" onchange="return stateColours()">
      <optgroup label="Aust States">
        <option value="0">select a state</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="NZ States">NZ States
        <option value="AU">Auckland</option>
        <option value="NO">Northland</option>
        <option value="SO">Southland</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-form-input">
    <label class="uk-form-label" id="postcodeLabel" name="postcodeLabel">Postcode:  
      <input class="uk-input" type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcodeInput" placeholder="0000" size="4" required="required" title="Postcode is incorrect for state" onblur="return validateErrors()" /> 
      <span class="uk-text-center" id="postcodeInputError" name="postcodeInputError" style="display: none;"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript:

```
function switchState() {
  var state = (document.getElementById("state").value);

  switch (state) {
    case "SA":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^5[0-9]{3}$/;
      break;
    case "NSW":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^2[0-9]{3}$/;
      break;
    case "VIC":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^3[0-9]{3}$/;
      break;
    case "ACT":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^3[0-9]{3}$/;
      break;
    case "QLD":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^4[0-­9]{3}$/;
      break;
    case "NT":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^08[0-9]{2}$/;
      break;
    case "TAS":
      var postcodeRegEx = /^7[0-9]{3}$/;
      break;
  }
  if (!postcodeRegEx.test(document.getElementById("postcodeInput").value))  {   //failure
    postcodeInput.style.background = '#FF9999';
    postcodeInputError.style.display = "block";
    postcodeInputError.innerHTML = postcodeInput.title;
    postcodeInput.focus();
    return  false;
  } 
  else  {
    //success
    postcodeInput.style.background = '#CCFFCC';
    postcodeInputError.style.display = "none";
    return  true; 
  }
```

Comment: What is `stateColours`, and where do you invoke `switchState`?

Comment: @a.matt, you are missing one function `validateErrors()` from code. I have placed a solution, but you need to fit it in your exact code. Also, you have one function called that doesn't exist and one that is not being called at all, but looks like it is just renaming issue and it is the same function

Answer (score 0):

You should bind event on change and call another function that checks country select values and depending on its value shows, hides `optgroup`. 
You can use querySelector to get correct optgroup element.

You will notice that I have removed `onchange` as inline attribute, and used `addEventListener` instead. It is more clear solution, and you have all js code at one place.

Also, you have called stateColours in inline onchange call, and switchState, so I have change to only one function name on both places, since it looks like that is the same function.

```js
var countrySelect = document.getElementById("country");
var stateSelect = document.getElementById("state");
var postCodeInput = document.getElementById("postcodeInput");

countrySelect.addEventListener('change', showHideOptGroup);
stateSelect.addEventListener('change', stateColours);
postCodeInput.addEventListener('blur', validateErrors);
showHideOptGroup(); //call it initially to hide all optgroups 

function showHideOptGroup(){
var country = (document.getElementById("country").value);
var stateSelect = document.querySelector("#state");
var AUOptGroup = stateSelect.querySelector('optgroup[label="Aust States"]');
var NZOptGroup = stateSelect.querySelector('optgroup[label="NZ States"]');

  if(country === 'AU'){
    AUOptGroup.style.display = "block";
  }else{
    AUOptGroup.style.display = "none";
  }

  if(country === 'NZ'){
   NZOptGroup.style.display = "block";
  }else{
   NZOptGroup.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  if(country === '0'){
  NZOptGroup.style.display = "none";
   AUOptGroup.style.display = "none";
  }
 
}

function stateColours(){ //you have called it stateColours in inline onchange call, and switchState, so I have unified it
var state = (document.getElementById("state").value);

switch (state)
{
    case "SA": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^5[0-9]{3}$/;
    break; 
    case "NSW": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^2[0-9]{3}$/;
    break;
    case "VIC": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^3[0-9]{3}$/;
    break;
    case "ACT": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^3[0-9]{3}$/;
    break;
    case "QLD": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^4[0-­9]{3}$/;
    break;
    case "NT": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^08[0-9]{2}$/;
    break;
    case "TAS": 
    postcodeRegEx=/^7[0-9]{3}$/;
    break;
    default: 
    postcodeRegEx = ''; //I have set it as default, since it looks like you haven't finished your switch statement for NZ states, so it doesn't throw errors below when calling test 
}
    if(postcodeRegEx!== undefined && postcodeRegEx!= '' && !postcodeRegEx.test(document.getElementById("postcodeInput").value))   //just remove first two checks for empty and undefined
        {  
        //failure
        postcodeInput.style.background='#FF9999';
        postcodeInputError.style.display="block";
        postcodeInputError.innerHTML=postcodeInput.title;
        postcodeInput.focus();
        return  false;
        }   
            else   
            {
                //success
                postcodeInput.style.background='#CCFFCC';
                postcodeInputError.style.display="none";
                return  true;    
            }  


}

//you haven't provided this code, but I have placed it, since it causes errors when it is called onblur
function validateErrors(){


}
```

```html
<div>Country:
<select class="uk-form-select" name="country" id="country" type="text" placeholder="select country first">      <option value="0">select country</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>State:  
<select type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="select state"> 
        <optgroup  label="Aust States">
            <option  value="0">select a state</option>
                <option  value="SA">SA</option>
                <option  value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option  value="VIC">VIC</option>
                <option  value="ACT">ACT</option>
                <option  value="TAS">TAS</option>
                <option  value="QLD">QLD</option>
                <option  value="NT">NT</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup  label="NZ States">NZ States  
                <option  value="AU">Auckland</option>
                <option  value="NO">Northland</option>
                <option  value="SO">Southland</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
<div class="uk-form-input">
    <label class="uk-form-label" id="postcodeLabel" name="postcodeLabel">Postcode:  
        <input class="uk-input" type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcodeInput" placeholder="0000" size="4" required="required" title="Postcode is incorrect for state"/> 
        <span class="uk-text-center" id="postcodeInputError" name="postcodeInputError" style="display: none;"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```